# Deploying and testing features on a server by more than one developer

Tags: git, bitbucket, branch, devops

I have 4 environments (prod/preprod/SIT/DEV), also two main branches (Master & Develop), two developers work on features (One & Two).

Developer One creates a feature (Feature A), he then merges the feature into the Develop branch.

Developer Two also creates a feature (Feature B) and he does the same, he merges the created feature into the Develop.

Now, the Develop branch will have two features (A & B), when the business owner decides to go with one feature ONLY (feature A), what should be the right approach to follow?

what is the best GIT workflow that we should follow? especially when implementing DevOps solutions.

P.S. I only mentioned two developers with two features, while in real life, I might have many more at the same time, hence I need to know the best approach to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Once you merged to Develop branch, assuming it's a shared branch, then it's hard to separate the features out.  Git revert can undo Feature B but if you have a lot of commits, this would not be feasible.

The best approach, IMO, is to keep the features on its own branches and only merge to Develop when the business owner makes a decision.